# Conditional api endpoints for different tables react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have am edit component that should be used for three of the tables in my database. However I'm running into `React Hook is called conditionally`. I want the conditional hooks because the table that is being updated needs to be changed based on which data I am editing. It seems like the only options are: do it like I have below which gives the hooks error, or split this into three separate components which goes against making reusable react components. Is this possible to do?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  TextField,
  FormControlLabel,
  Checkbox,
  FormGroup,
  Button
} from "@mui/material";
import { 
  useAddAttractionMutation,
  useFetchAttractionQuery,
  useUpdateAttractionMutation,
  useRemoveAttractionMutation,
  useAddRestaurantMutation,
  useFetchRestaurantQuery,
  useUpdateRestaurantMutation,
  useRemoveRestaurantMutation,
  useAddShowMutation,
  useFetchShowQuery,
  useUpdateShowMutation,
  useRemoveShowMutation,
} from "../store/apis/dappApi";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import { PARK_AREAS } from "../constants";

function Edit({ type }) {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const parks = Object.keys(PARK_AREAS);

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [park, setPark] = useState(parks[0]);
  const [area, setArea] = useState(PARK_AREAS[park][0]);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);

  let mutationVariables;

  if (type === "attractions") {
    mutationVariables = {
      addMutation: useAddAttractionMutation()[0],
      updateMutation: useUpdateAttractionMutation()[0],
      removeMutation: useRemoveAttractionMutation()[0],
      fetchData: useFetchAttractionQuery(id),
    };
  } else if (type === "restaurants") {
    mutationVariables = {
      addMutation: useAddRestaurantMutation()[0],
      updateMutation: useUpdateRestaurantMutation()[0],
      removeMutation: useRemoveRestaurantMutation()[0],
      fetchData: useFetchRestaurantQuery(id),
    };
  } else if (type === "shows") {
    mutationVariables = {
      addMutation: useAddShowMutation()[0],
      updateMutation: useUpdateShowMutation()[0],
      removeMutation: useRemoveShowMutation()[0],
      fetchData: useFetchShowQuery(id),
    };
  }
  
  const {
    addMutation,
    updateMutation,
    removeMutation,
    fetchData: { data, isLoading },
  } = mutationVariables;
  
  const handleDelete = () => {
    removeMutation(id);
    navigate(`/${type}`);
  }

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    const updateData = {
      id,
      name,
      park,
      area,
      completed,
    };

    updateMutation(updateData);
    navigate(`/${type}`);
  }

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const attractionData = {
      name,
      park,
      area,
      completed
    };

    addMutation(attractionData);
    navigate(`/${type}`);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && id != null) {
      setPark(data.park);
      setCompleted(data.completed);
      setName(data.name);
      setArea(data.area);
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center">Loading...</div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <FormGroup className="flex flex-col m-6 gap-4">
        <TextField label="Name" 
          value={name}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setName(event.target.value);
          }}
        />       
        <Dropdown
          options={parks}
          value={park}
          label="Park"
          setValue={setPark}
        />
        <Dropdown
          options={PARK_AREAS[park]}
          value={area}
          label="Area"
          setValue={setArea}
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={completed}
              onChange={(event) => {
                setCompleted(event.target.checked);
              }}
            />
          }
          label="Completed"
        />
        <div
          className="outline rounded-lg h-80 flex justify-center align-center"
        >
          map will go here
        </div>
        {id != null ? (
          <div className="flex justify-center gap-4">            
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleUpdate}>
              Save
            </Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="error" onClick={handleDelete}>
              Delete
            </Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleAdd}>Create</Button>
          </div>
        )}
      </FormGroup>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Edit;

Edit.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

I tried moving to a custom hook but got the same problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't conditionally call React hooks. To get around this you'll just need to call all the hooks unconditionally. Assign the mutation triggers and query results to unique identifiers and use the `skip` option to [conditionally](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching) run the queries.

```js
const [addAttractionTrigger] = useAddAttractionMutation();
const [updateAttractionTrigger] = useUpdateAttractionMutation();
const [removeAttractionTrigger] = useRemoveAttractionMutation();
const fetchAttractionResult = useFetchAttractionQuery(
  id,
  { skip: !["restaurants", "shows"].includes(type) } // "attractions"
);

const [addRestaurantTrigger] = useAddRestaurantMutation();
const [updateRestaurantTrigger] = useUpdateRestaurantMutation();
const [removeRestaurantTrigger] = useRemoveRestaurantMutation();
const fetchRestaurantResult = useFetchRestaurantQuery(
  id,
  { skip: !["attractions", "shows"].includes(type) } // "restaurants"
);

const [addShowTrigger] = useAddShowMutation();
const [updateShowTrigger] = useUpdateShowMutation();
const [removeShowTrigger] = useRemoveShowMutation();
const fetchShowResult = useFetchShowQuery(
  id,
  { skip: !["attractions", "restaurants"].includes(type) } // "shows"
);

let mutationVariables;

if (type === "attractions") {
  mutationVariables = {
    addMutation: addAttractionTrigger,
    updateMutation: updateAttractionTrigger,
    removeMutation: removeAttractionTrigger,
    fetchData: fetchAttractionResult,
  };
} else if (type === "restaurants") {
  mutationVariables = {
    addMutation: addRestaurantTrigger,
    updateMutation: updateRestaurantTrigger,
    removeMutation: removeRestaurantTrigger,
    fetchData: fetchRestaurantResult,
  };
} else if (type === "shows") {
  mutationVariables = {
    addMutation: addShowTrigger,
    updateMutation: updateShowTrigger,
    removeMutation: removeShowTrigger,
    fetchData: fetchShowResult,
  };
}
  
const {
  addMutation,
  updateMutation,
  removeMutation,
  fetchData: { data, isLoading },
} = mutationVariables;
```